# 64-bit LDR/STR not 8-byte aligned with Release mode only

Tags: objective-c, 64-bit, llvm, osx-yosemite, xcode7

I'd like to report my problem when build with RELEASE mode.
I do not why it's working fine with DEBUG mode. I also checked in detail the debug mode setting and release mode setting , but there is no reason.

> ld: 64-bit LDR/STR not 8-byte aligned: from -[CatchingAction
>   initWithViewController:] (0x1000425E0) to _num (0x10082EC4C) in
>   '-[CatchingAction
>   initWithViewControllerbbw/Build/Intermediates/Myapp.build/Release-iphoneos/Myapp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CatchingAction.o
>   for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Here is my environment:
1. MacBook Pro : OS X Yosemite 10.10.5
2. Xcode : Version 7.0 ( I have tried to build with 7.1 too)

Comment: Have you tried quitting Xcode and removing the ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData folder ?

Comment: You mean delete all of contents of DerivedData folder ?  
I will try

Comment: I have already tried it. It still does NOT work .